# How to loop through all files subdirectory and add pupulate the files in the found file python

Tags: python

I am looking to find the files with specific names with specific text in them and add specific text as a specific line.

I hope it makes sense what I am looking to achieve.

```
from pathlib import Path
filesDir="D:/OneDrive/Desktop/testpy/"
for file in Path(filesDir).rglob('*.ini'):
    with file.open as in_file:
        buf = in_file.readlines()

    with file.open as out_file:
        for line in buf:
            if line == "sometext":
                line = line + "mytext"
            out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open is a **method**, so use *file.open()*. Also check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details.

Comment: In particular, you've provided some code. What happens if you run that code? What do you want to happen when you run that code? How are those two things different?

Comment: If this code doesn't do what you want, then you need to **explain**.  Show us what the code does, and tell us what you expected instead.

Comment: @DouglasWinship I am looking to populate the text files in the subfolders that have the same extension. Each file might have multiple lines with the same "sometext" and I need to append if that text is found.  The error code :
 File "D:\OneDrive\Desktop\testpy\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    out_file.write(line + '\n')
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically right. The only problem is that `line` has a newline at the end, you need to remove it before comparing, and add it back before writing.

Also, `open` is a function, you need parentheses to call it. And you have to specify `w` mode when opening it for output.

```
from pathlib import Path
filesDir="D:/OneDrive/Desktop/testpy/"
for file in Path(filesDir).rglob('*.ini'):
    with file.open() as in_file:
        buf = in_file.readlines()

    with file.open('w') as out_file:
        for line in buf:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if line == "sometext":
                line = line + "mytext"
            out_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: I just tested it with a file with two lines containing `sometext`, it replaced both with `sometextmytext`.

Comment: You understand that this only matches if the entire line is exactly `sometext`, it's not looking for a substring, right?

Comment: Oh! got it. Thank you @Barmar! your solution worked!
I can't mark it as useful as I do not have the necessary score to do it.

Comment: You can always accept the answer to your own question. Click on the check mark.

Comment: are you able to help me further to expand this a little more? Each file contains a unique string, I want to create a list/array that whenever finds that file with unique string to add "mytext" which will be dedicated for each file (another list that will have them in order as well as the unique string). Please let me know if you understand the idea? Thank you

Comment: Looks like you already got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77797484/loop-through-multiple-files-match-the-list-with-the-unique-word-then-append-tex)