# loop through multiple files, match the list with the unique word then append text from a list to the corresponding to the file python

Tags: python

Each file contains a unique string, I want to create a list/array that whenever find that file with a unique string adds "mytext" which will be dedicated for each file (another list that will have them in order as well as the unique string).
Please let me know if you understand the idea.

```
string=["444","445"]
input=["text-444","text-445"]
from pathlib import Path
filesDir="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/pythone-env/"
for file in Path(filesDir).rglob('*.ini'):
    with file.open() as in_file:
        buf = in_file.readlines()

        
    with file.open("w") as out_file:
        for line in buf:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            for word in string:
                for word in line: 
                    if line == "subnetIP=255.255.255.0":
                        line = line + input
                    out_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: What is the problem you’re facing? Is the program not working as you expect it to?

Comment: So you have a list of files, and for each file you want to replace any instance of "subnetIP=255.255.255.0" with a string that is specific to that file? Is that your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated version after comments

Okay so this will search every .ini file in the folder and subfolders. For each it will search for one of the `search_strings`, once it finds one it will add a new line after the `subnet...` line with the corresponding `input_string`. I've tried to be very detailed with the comments so it is clear what it is doing.

```
from pathlib import Path

# a list of strings to search for in each file
search_strings = ["444", "445"]

# a corresponding list of strings to insert if the search string is found
input_strings = ["text-444", "text-445"]

# search every .ini file in the directory and its subdirectories
filesDir = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/pythone-env/"
for file in Path(filesDir).rglob('*.ini'):
    # read the file into a list of lines
    with file.open() as in_file:
        lines = in_file.readlines()

    # work out which search string is in the file (by default, None)
    ind = None

    # check every search string in turn
    for i in range(len(search_strings)):
        # if the search string is in the file then record its index and stop searching
        if search_strings[i] in ''.join(lines):
            ind = i
            break

    # if no search string is found in the file then continue to next file
    if ind is None:
        continue

    # otherwise, find the subnet line and insert the input string after it
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if "subnetIP=255.255.255.0" in line:
            lines.insert(i + 1, input_strings[ind] + '\n')
            break

    # write the modified lines back to the file
    with file.open("w") as out_file:
        out_file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Tom. This looks above my skills and I appreciated. I have tried it but for some reason the file can't be found on the directory

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exact error you get? And also what files you expect it to find? (That code block will only work if every .ini file in the directory is named either `444.ini` or `445.ini`)

Comment: oh I see, apologies for the confusion.
 What I mean is when "x.ini" file has a string with "444"  and "y.ini" file is under another subfolder with a string "445". get matched from the list it will insert the "input" after any line in the file that has "subnetIP=255.255.255.0" for each file found that has the matched the string

Comment: Sorry I think I still don't quite understand your goal with the code. Is this what you mean: there are 3 arrays, 1 with a list of files, 1 with a list of test strings to search for, and 1 with a list of inputs. You want to search each file and, if it contains the test string, insert the input string after the "subnet..."?

Comment: everything you said but without the array with a list of files.
Thank you so much for your responses

Comment: Gotcha, happy to help! Okay if it's not file specific then can you guarantee only one of the test strings will be in the file?

Comment: Correctly. As soon as it matches the string anywhere in the file it will append the correct text from the array/list. Each text corresponds to a file The file needs to be identified and searched across each subfolder and that part of the code works perfectly on my end. Many thanks Tom!

Comment: Great, in that case I think my updated answer should do what you want. You're welcome!

Comment: Hi Tom, that worked perfectly! you are a legend!